# Properties of class parameter are always null in Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my web api controller there is an action method like below

```
 [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
    public IReportOutput InsuranceHandlingFiles([FromBody]CaseCountsInputData caseCountsInputData)
    {

    }
```

Parameter class of this action is

```
[Serializable]
public class CaseCountsInputData
{
    public string MainTitle { get; set; }
    public string YearTitle { get; set; }
    public string InsurerFileCountTitle { get; set; }
    public List<FileCount> FileCounts { get; set; }
    public int InsurerTotalCount { get; set; }
    public int GrandTotal { get; set; }
    public string TotalTitle { get; set; }
    public string GrandTotalTitle { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class FileCount
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public int InsurerFilesCount { get; set; }
}
```

I call this API method for testing purposes as follows. My action is called this way and my json object is binded to CaseCountsInputData class but all parameters are null. Can you help me exactly where I made the mistake?

```
            $("#btnExport")
            .click(function() {
            var reportData = GetReportData();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(reportData));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(reportData),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "http://localhost:50773/api/export/insurancehandlingfiles",
                    success: function(data) {
                          var DocumentBody = data.Data;
                    var FileName = data.FileName;
                    dataURItoBlob(DocumentBody, FileName);
                    },
                    error: function(error,as,asd) {

                        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                        alert("error" + error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
    });

    function GetReportData() {

        var reportModel = {
            CaseCountsInputData: {
                MainTitle: "Dosya Sayısı",
                YearTitle: "Yıl",
                InsurerFileCountTitle: "Sigortacı Dosya Sayısı",
                TotalTitle: "Toplam",
                GrandTotalTitle: "Genel Toplam",
                InsurerTotalCount: 1,
                GrandTotal: 3,
                FileCounts: []
            }
        }
        var caseCounts =[];
        caseCounts.push({
            "year": 2014,
            "InsurerFilesCount": 1
        });
          caseCounts.push({
            "year": 2015,
            "InsurerFilesCount": 4
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < caseCounts.length; i++) {
            reportModel.CaseCountsInputData.FileCounts.push(caseCounts[i]);
        }

        return reportModel;
    }
```

Comment: Your json is incorrect, it's rooted inside of a property called CaseCountsInputData which doesn't exist in your model's object graph.  The way to know exactly how the json should look is to send your model's object graph through json.net's serialization, either manually or by observing it in the browser in response to some ajax request.  You can then re-create the correct json format on the client side to send back to the server.

Comment: Can u do like this and check var Data = {
                MainTitle: "Dosya Sayısı",
                YearTitle: "Yıl",
                InsurerFileCountTitle: "Sigortacı Dosya Sayısı",
                TotalTitle: "Toplam",
                GrandTotalTitle: "Genel Toplam",
                InsurerTotalCount: 1,
                GrandTotal: 3,
                FileCounts: []
            }

Comment: please try to stringify  the 'CaseCountsInputData'(i.e reportModel.CaseCountsInputData) instead of reportModel itself, when sending it in the ajax requet

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(reportData.CaseCountsInputData)

Comment: All the suggestions are the same and totally correct. Thank you all :)