# Asp.Net Web Api Passing Class That Has Multiple Class Properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I had the question in the previous question on the link below, and the changes in the comments were resolved.

[Properties of class parameter are always null in Asp.Net Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976554/properties-of-class-parameter-are-always-null-in-asp-net-web-api?noredirect=1#comment73045954_42976554)

But this time the problem is a bit different. The method parameter is another class that has more than one class type property.

```
  [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header")]
    public IReportOutput InsuranceHandlingFiles([FromBody]InsuranceHandlingFilesInput insuranceHandlingFilesInput)
    {

    }

    public class InsuranceHandlingFilesInput
    {
    public CaseCountsInput CaseCountsInput { get; set; }
    public MioEurosInput MioEurosInput { get; set; }
    public SharesInput SharesInput { get; set; }
    }
```

After creating the Json object belonging to this class in the following way, I send the post with the request of Post. But even though the first property comes in correctly filled, the other properties are null. How can I solve this problem?

```
       function GetReportData() {

        var reportModel = {
            CaseCountsInput: {
                    MainTitle: "Dosya Sayısı",
                    YearTitle: "Yıl",
                    InsurerFileCountTitle: "Sigortacı Dosya Sayısı",
                    TotalTitle: "Toplam",
                    GrandTotalTitle: "Genel Toplam",
                    InsurerTotalCount: 1,
                    GrandTotal: 3,
                    FileCounts: []
            },
            MioEurosInput :{
                    MainTitle:"Incurred Sums - Mio Euro",
                    YearTitle:"Year",
                    InsurerIncurredTitle:"Insurer Incurred",
                    TotalTitle:"Total",
                    GrandTotalTitle:"Grand Total",
                    MioEuros :[],
                    InsurerIncurredTotal:0.11,
                    GrandTotal:0.28
            },
            SharesInput :{
                    MainTitle:"Incurred Shares (%)",
                    YearTitle:"Year",
                    InsurerIncurredShareTitle:"Insurer Incurred (%)",
                    TotalTitle:"Total",
                    GrandTotalTitle:"Grand Total",
                    ShareDatas:[],
                    InsurerIncurredShareTotal:39.29,
                    GrandTotal:100
            }
        }
        var caseCounts =[];
            caseCounts.push({
            "year": 2014,
            "InsurerFilesCount": 1
        });
            caseCounts.push({
            "year": 2015,
            "InsurerFilesCount": 4
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < caseCounts.length; i++) {
            reportModel.CaseCountsInput.FileCounts.push(caseCounts[i]);
        }

        var mioEuroData =[];
        mioEuroData.push({
            "year": 2016,
            "InsurerMioEuro": 0
        });
        mioEuroData.push({
            "year": 2017,
            "InsurerMioEuro": 0.11
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < mioEuroData.length; i++) {
            reportModel.MioEurosInput.MioEuros.push(mioEuroData[i]);
        }

         var shares=[];
        shares.push({
            "year": 2016,
            "insurerShare": 0
        }); 
        shares.push({
            "year": 2017,
            "insurerShare": 45.83
        });             
        for (var i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
            reportModel.SharesInput.ShareDatas.push({year:shares[i].year,InsurerIncurredShare:shares[i].insurerShare,ArcelikIncurredShare:shares[i].arcelikShare});
        }

        return reportModel;
    }

            $("#btnExport")
            .click(function() {
            var reportData = GetReportData();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(reportData));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({CaseCountsInput:reportData.CaseCountsInput,MioEurosInput:reportData.MioEurosInput,SharesInput:reportData.SharesInput}),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "http://localhost:50773/api/export/insurancehandlingfiles",
                    success: function(data) {
                          var DocumentBody = data.ReportData;
                    var FileName = data.FileName;
                    dataURItoBlob(DocumentBody, FileName);
                    },
                    error: function(error,as,asd) {

                        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                        alert("error" + error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Change it to data: JSON.stringify(reportData);

Comment: I tried that way but nothing changed :( @BasantaMatia

Comment: Are you getting data in console here console.log(JSON.stringify(reportData));

Comment: You have written wrong. create separate array for all the 3 classes. Then create a new array ex: var Data = {1stclass: myFirstclassArray, 2ndclass:mySecondClassArray, so on} Then JSON.stringify(Data); Thats it

Comment: I realized that I was completely careless because of the mistake. The class is null because I try to serialize a property of type double to type int.